# In PHP, using no output buffering, cannot write more than 400 lines in Chrome

Tags: php, output-buffering

This is a simple loop to print out 1000 lines. 
On my Windows 7 machine using Chrome and Zend Server, it shows only 400 lines and then stops without any error.

If I change the time delay in usleep() to 200ms, it shows 600 lines and then stops.

If I set the set_time_limit () to 20secs, it shows about 100 lines and then gives error: "Fatal Error: Maximum Execution time limit...".

Did I miss any system setting that made the execution stops abruptly like that ? I look at the logs and don't see any error.

```
<?php
// Turn off output buffering and set implicit flush on
@ini_set('implicit_flush', 1);
@ini_set('output_bufferring', 0);
@ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);
for ($i = 0; $i < ob_get_level(); $i++)
    ob_end_flush();
// Stop output buffering
ob_implicit_flush(1);

set_time_limit(0);

// MAIN LOOP to print out a line 1000 times 
for ($i=0; $i<1000;$i++) {
    $buf = sprintf("Line %04d ".str_repeat(" ", 1010)."<br>", $i);
    echo "$buf\n";
    usleep(300000);
}

echo "End of execution<br>\n";

?>
```

Comment: So you're `sleeping` the process between each line of output until it hits a timeout limit! PHP has its timeout limit defined in php.ini, and the default timeout for a webserver like Apache is typically 5 minutes

Comment: No! The set_time_limit(0) should set the execution timeout limit to UNLIMITED - usleep(300000) will sleep only 1/3 of a second to print out a line.

Comment: If you're running this through a web access, then the webserver has a timeout that isn't changed by any php.ini settings

Comment: Thanks Mark - So there is no way to extend or change the webserver's timeout ? I run this small app OK in a DOS window. Any suggestion to run a long long long application in a Web browser like Chrome ??

Comment: You can increase the webserver timeout via the webserver configuration file: but if something takes this long to run then it's almost certainly best to submit it as a background task to be run via a cron or similar as a command line task

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to up the max execution time, an ini setting: http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php for info in runtime configuration, if you can't change the php.ini.